Not able to retrieve Angular signal from service
I am trying to use a service to be able to put the selected division object in a service and then retrieve it in the detail form. the code for the service is:
 private currentDivision = signal<Division>(new Division(), undefined);

  setCurrentDivision(division: Division): void {
    this.currentDivision.set(division);
    console.log(this.currentDivision());
  }
  getCurrentDivision(): Division {
    console.log(this.currentDivision());
    return this.currentDivision();
  }

The code for the list is
onSelect(division: Division): void {
    this._divisionService.setCurrentDivision(division);
  }


The code for the detail form is:
divisionService = inject(DivisionService);
  constructor(private fb: UntypedFormBuilder) {

    console.log(this.divisionService.getCurrentDivision());
    this.division = this.divisionService.getCurrentDivision();
  }


I should be able to see the object value in the console and I can see when I do the set that it is populated but then it turns to null when I retrieve it.

The thing is, that you are latching yourself with current signal value by
   this.division = this.divisionService.getCurrentDivision();
For signals to work, you have to fetch it value over and over again (via yourSignal())
Therfore, either return Signal<Devision> from the service, or change component property to getter so every access will end up in accessing singnal value
ivisionService = inject(DivisionService);
  constructor(private fb: UntypedFormBuilder) {
    console.log(this.divisionService.getCurrentDivision());
  }

  get division(){
//this will do the trick
    this.divisionService.getCurrentDivision();
  }

In current form of DivisionService, signals are useless and it works exactly the same as you would only have plain
private currentDivision:Divison = undefined
in there instead of sig.
